# Slice up an uint8_t array

Tags: c, arrays, uint8t

Let's say that I have an array of 16 `uint8_t` as follows:

`uint8_t array[] = {0x13, 0x01, 0x4E, 0x52, 0x31, 0x4A, 0x35, 0x36, 0x4C, 0x11, 0x21, 0xC6, 0x3C, 0x73, 0xC2, 0x41};`

This array stores the data contained in a 128 bits register of an external peripheral. Some of the information it represents are stored on 2, 3, 8, 12 bits ... and so on.

What is the best and elegant way to slice it up and bit mask the information I need? (The problem is that some things that I need overlaps the length of one cell of the array)

If that can help, this snippet I wrote converts the whole array into a char* string. But casting this into an `int` is not option because.. well 16 bytes.

```
int i;
char str[33];
for(i = 0; i < sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array) ; i++) {
    sprintf(str+2*i,"%02hX",array[i]);
}
puts(str);
```

> 13014E52314A35364C1121C63C73C241

Comment: Your `str` is too short and your program will invoke *undefined behavior* for dereferencing out-of-range if `sizeof(array) >= 8`. It should be at least 33 (`2 * 16 + 1`)-character long. Also do not forget to terminate the string by adding `'\0'` before passing the data to `puts()`. Another point is that `sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array)` should be safer to get the number of elements of the array.

Comment: You're absolutely right, it's weird it doesn't yield my any error whatsoever when compiling nor running... It just prints out the whole thing even if the memory is not allocated for it. It was just food for thoughts anyway, I'm editing this to be correct, thanks

Comment: Ah, I noticed that `sprintf()` will terminate the string, so you don't have to do it by yourself.

Comment: Exactly what I was just typing. I just tried that in debug, it does terminate the string

Comment: Non portable, but you could probably use bitfields in a packed datastructure

Comment: Sadly I need it to be portable :/

Comment: How about using a plain old struct to store the data instead of `uint8_t array[]` ? The struct's members would match the fields of the register.

Comment: I can't do that because the data comes from an SPI transfer, the SDK I've got stores each byte in an array

Comment: Please explain the requirement `slice it up and bit mask the information I need`. In other words, what exactly is the output that you want?

Comment: I think the best output that I could get is hex strings for each slice? The thing is, it depends on the info. For instance the first set of 2 bits is the device type, so 0,1 or 2 in decimal for 3 different devices. But further is product name, so I expect a format that I could convert to ASCII. After that is a serial number etc etc...\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually such problem also occures when trying to parse all kind of bitstreams, like video or image files or compressed data by algorithms like LZ*. So the approach used there is to implement a bitstream reader.

But in your case the bit sequence is fixed length and quite short, so one way is to manually check the field values using bitwise operations.

Or you can use this function that I just wrote, which can extract arbitrary number of bits from a uint8 array, starting from desired bit position:

```
uint32_t extract_bits(uint8_t *arr, unsigned int bit_index, unsigned int bit_count)
{
    /* Assert that we are not requested to extract more than 32 bits */
    uint32_t result = 0;
    assert(bit_count <= sizeof(result)*8 && arr != NULL);

    /* You can additionally check if you are trying to extract bits exceeding the 16 byte range */
    assert(bit_index + bit_count <= 16 * 8);

    unsigned int arr_id = bit_index / 8;
    unsigned int bit_offset = bit_index % 8;

    if (bit_offset > 0) {
        /* Extract first 'unaligned_bit_count' bits, which happen to be non-byte-aligned.
         * When we do extract those bits, the remaining will be byte-aligned so
         * we will thread them in different manner.
         */
        unsigned int unaligned_bit_count = 8 - bit_offset;

        /* Check if we need less than the remaining unaligned bits */
        if (bit_count < unaligned_bit_count) {
            result = (arr[arr_id] >> bit_offset) & ((1 << bit_count) - 1);
            return result;
        }

        /* We need them all */
        result = arr[arr_id] >> bit_offset;
        bit_count -= unaligned_bit_count;

        /* Move to next byte element */
        arr_id++;
    }

    while (bit_count > 0) {
        /* Try to extract up to 8 bits per iteration */
        int bits_to_extract = bit_count > 8 ? 8 : bit_count;

        if (bits_to_extract < 8) {
            result = (result << bits_to_extract) | (arr[arr_id] & ((1 << bits_to_extract)-1));
        }else {
            result = (result << bits_to_extract) | arr[arr_id];
        }

        bit_count -= bits_to_extract;
        arr_id++;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Here is example of how it is used.

```
uint32_t r;

/* Extracts bits [7..8] and places them as most significant bits of 'r' */  
r = extract_bits(arr, 7, 2)

/* Extracts bits [4..35] and places them as most significant bits of 'r' */  
r = extract_bits(arr, 4, 32);

/* Visualize */
printf("slice=%x\n", r);
```

And then the visualisation of `r` is up to you. They can either be represented as hex dwords, characters, or however you decide.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is awesome. I was kind of writing something along those lines but your code is much much cleaner haha.
Tested and working fine.